# Can you pick up inherited element class with jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, inheritance

If I have this:

```
<div class="abc">
     <input class="edf">
</div>
```

Does the input tag inherits the `class="abc"`? So the input tag is actually `<input class="edf abc">`?

If it does, can I use jquery to pick up the `class="abc"` from the input tag by using `class="edf"`?

I am trying to do some event to the input tag and I am trying to only pick up the input tag by using the class name `class="edf"` due to design limitation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, the `<input>` element does not inherit the class(es) of parent elements. However, the selector

```
.abc .edf
```

will match that `<input>`. So, via jQuery,

```
var $input = $(".abc input.edf");
```

would match your input, but not match:

```
<div id="someOtherDiv" class="xyz">
  <input class="edf">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

No, classes are not being inherited by DOM elements. You have to add them explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

No it does not inherit class like you think it is, that being sad it is a child of a parent.
You can select a class  edf like such $(".abc .adf")   or you can select abc from edf by doing this $(".edf").parent() or $(".edf").parents(".abc");